# Java 8 Streams: collector returning filtered object

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

Say I have a Set that I'd like to filter down to the oldest per school.

So far I have:

```
Map<String, Long> getOldestPerSchool(Set<Person> persons) {
  return persons.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getSchoolname, Person::getAge, Long::max);
}
```

Trouble is, I want the whole person instead of only the name. But if I change it to:

```
Map<Person, Long> getOldestPerSchool(Set<Person> persons) {
  return persons.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p, Person::getAge, Long::max);
}
```

I get all persons, and I do not necessarily need a Map.

Comment: So why not filter out the ones you don't want, and collect other than with `toMap()`?

Comment: @daniu: Because there's no Person:isOldestinSchool method. I need to compare it with the others of that School. But perhaps you know of a way?

Comment: Why are you collecting the ages as values instead of the persons? And why is your solution to change the *keys* to the whole persons? The keys should still be the school name. The values should be whole persons, and you should adapt the merge function to that.

Comment: give this guy a break...  he obviously knows that his solution does not work. that is why he is asking here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Set that I'd like to filter down to the oldest per school.

Assuming oldest per school meant *oldest `Person` per `school`*, you are possibly looking for an output like:

```
Map<String, Person> getOldestPersonPerSchool(Set<Person> persons) {
    return persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Person::getSchoolname,  // school name
                    Function.identity(), // person
                    (a, b) -> a.getAge() > b.getAge() ? a : b)); // ensure to store oldest (no tie breaker for same age)
}
```

Comment: Oh, now I feel a bit dumb when looking at my answer, didn't think it could be that easy :D

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with an intermediate grouping and then only streaming over the `values()` of the resulting grouped list, there you just select the oldest person

```
Set<Person> oldestPerSchool = persons.stream()             // Stream<Person>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getSchoolname)) // Map<String, List<Person>>
    .values().stream()                                     // Stream<List<Person>>
    .map(list -> list.stream()                             // (Inner) Stream<Person>
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge))      // (Inner) Optional<Person>
        .get()                                             // (Inner) Person
    )                                                      // Stream<Person>
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());                          // Set<Person>
```

Comment: `groupingBy` accepts a downstream Collector, you don't need to re-stream the values.